# SQL query stemmer removing quotes and ending character

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently If a user inputs company name as "Bob's Place", my stemmer will remove 's and return "Bob Place".  However I'm having issue with sql data side

What I would like to do is bring back companys that match the stemmed word, however in the database side has the company name "Bob's Place".

Any way i can remove `'s` and compare "bob place"?

```
select * 
from ops..companyinfo with(nolock) 
where SUBSTRING(name, 0, charindex(CHAR(39),name))  like '%bob place%'
```

Currently its comparing 'bob' = 'bob place'

Currently need if a company in the database name called Mike's Place need to be Mike place

Comment: Don't fight with string manipulation use paramaterized queries instead. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx  but if you must use the "Replace" function

Answer (score 1):

If you must:

```
select * from ops..companyinfo with(nolock) 
where REPLACE(Name, '''s', '')  like '%bob place%'
```

but you'll be far better off in the long run using parameterized queries http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2008/09/30/how-and-why-to-use-parameterized-queries.aspx or even better:
http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/

Don't change user input without letting them know you changed it.

In some cases if you generate an invoice from your saved data and your removing the ' when saving names... Bob's Place isn't the same legally as Bobs place  It's just bad form to change user data.  Save what they key in.  Return what they key in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below, in case you are not removing `'s` and do the comparison directly.

```
select 1 where replace('Bob''s Place','''','') = 'Bobs Place'
```

In your case it would be

```
select * 
from ops..companyinfo with(nolock) 
where replace(name,'''','')  = 'Bobs Place'
```